# Should spring boot write to the quartz database table(s) (aka QRTZ_TRIGGERS) when using only @Scheduled(cron='?')?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, quartz

I've configured quartz manually before, but I thought that this time around, i would try and utilize as much of the spring-boot (2.7.4) magic as I could.

(I also want to say, it's entirely possible I was hoping for too much, but would appreciate any feedback. At the end of the day, I was hoping/thinking that using the @Scheduled annotation, would be sufficient to get the quartz jobs/triggers copied into the database-backed quartz tables.

The desired end state should result with the system being clustered, with the jobs stored in the application defined  dataSource. The application where the job runs is deployed to a cloud environment with multiple running instances, and we only need one of those apps to acutally do this work.

From the quartz/spring perspective, I have the following config.

```
spring.quartz.scheduler-name=super-duper-scheduler
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.job-store.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LocalDataSourceJobStore
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

In the code, in a spring component i have:

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */20 * * * *")
    public void updateVendorInfoFromSam() {
      ... doing stuff
    }
```

Looking at the logs after startup, everything looks about how i would expect

```
2023-08-08 09:14:12,264 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2023-08-08 09:14:12,273 [main] INFO  o.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2023-08-08 09:14:12,274 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2023-08-08 09:14:12,306 [main] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
2023-08-08 09:14:12,307 [main] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - JobStoreCMT initialized.
2023-08-08 09:14:12,307 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'super-duper-scheduler' with instanceId '@#$@#$@#$'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

2023-08-08 09:14:12,308 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'super-duper-scheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2023-08-08 09:14:12,308 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2023-08-08 09:14:12,308 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@1727d525
```

When I manually check the quartz database tables, a few tables have some minimum of data, but the jobs and triggers tables (which historically have held the job and trigger info) are not being written to (well at least, nothing is persisting). (Not sure that it matters at this point, but that ds has autocommit turned off.)

The overarching question I have is..... *should* I expect to set up a job in spring, using only the @Scheduled annotation, and have it run in a clustered manner (aka. only run on one instance) using quartz?

Comment: you can also check ShedLock to run scheduled jobs on multiple instances, but right now if it's enough to run on only 1 instance, then stay keep it up.

Comment: This doesn't anwer the actual question. However, ShedLock does provide another tool on the belt if your primary need is to prevent job execution across multiple running instances of an application/job.